# Why is the tableadapter namespace different from that of the dataset?

Tags: ado.net, dataset, .net-2.0, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

I know this may sound a little basic but I was wondering why the tableadapter namespace different from that of the dataset?

Was it something I did when I generated it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using TableAdapter? It's kind of old technology. What about using Entity Framework?

Comment: We are moving to that in a total rewrite. Unfortunately, the app (I've inherited) is currently rooted in VS2005. To make matters worse, sql is embedded in the forms/controls. I may be wrong but I didn't think I could use the entity framework in VS2005?

Comment: No, you can't use EF in VS2005. It uses .NET 2.0.